# My bubble sort over a double linked list cuts off the first node of the list for some reason

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

Here's the method

```
public void sortStudentsAlphabeticallyByFirstName()
{
    StudentNode unsorted = tail;
    StudentNode current = header;
    while(unsorted.prevNode() != null)
    {
        while(current != unsorted)
        {
            int result = (current.getFirstName()).compareToIgnoreCase(current.nextNode().getFirstName());
            if(result > 0) //If in wrong order lexicographically
            {
                StudentNode temp = current;
                StudentNode next = current.nextNode();
                StudentNode previous = current.prevNode();
                StudentNode nextNext = next.nextNode();
                if (numberOfStudents() == 2) 
                {
                    current = current.nextNode();
                    current.setNext(temp);
                    temp.setPrev(current);
                    temp.setNext(null);
                    current.setPrev(null);
                    unsorted = temp;
                }
                else if(nextNext == null) //If at penultimate student therefore last comparison
                {
                    current = current.nextNode();
                    current.setNext(temp);
                    temp.setPrev(current);
                    temp.setNext(null);
                    previous.setNext(current);
                    current.setPrev(previous);
                    unsorted = temp;
                }
                else if(previous == null) //if at beginning of student list
                {
                    if(current.nextNode() == unsorted)
                    {
                        current = current.nextNode();
                        current.setNext(temp);
                        temp.setPrev(current);
                        temp.setNext(nextNext);
                        nextNext.setPrev(temp);  
                        current.setPrev(null); 
                        unsorted = temp; //swap unsorted back to correct position
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        current = current.nextNode();
                        current.setNext(temp);
                        temp.setPrev(current);
                        temp.setNext(nextNext);
                        nextNext.setPrev(temp);  
                        current.setPrev(null);
                    }
                }
                else  //else if in the middle of the list
                {
                    if(current.nextNode() == unsorted)
                    {
                        current = current.nextNode();
                        current.setNext(temp);
                        temp.setPrev(current);
                        temp.setNext(nextNext);
                        nextNext.setPrev(temp);  
                        previous.setNext(current);
                        current.setPrev(previous); 
                        unsorted = temp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        current = current.nextNode();
                        current.setNext(temp);
                        temp.setPrev(current);
                        temp.setNext(nextNext);
                        nextNext.setPrev(temp);  
                        previous.setNext(current);
                        current.setPrev(previous); 
                    }
                }
            }
            current = current.nextNode();
        }
        current = header;
        unsorted = unsorted.prevNode();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see why it cuts off the beginning of the list when I try to iterate the list again? I've used the debugger and it seems to run like it should, but I can't work out why it's doing it.

Here's the iterate list method as well if it helps

```
public void itterateList()
{
    StudentNode u = header;
    while(u != null)
    {
        System.out.println(u.getFirstName()+" "+u.getSurname());
        u = u.nextNode();
    }
}
```

Comment: BubbleSort. Don't get me started!

Comment: You shouldn't iterate through the original variable but through temp only. Since it references it, saying next on that would be the same as saying next to current. That way you keep the head at all times, and untouched.

Comment: @Andy Sorry I don't quite get what you mean. Which original variable?

Comment: Could you just explain a bit as to how you decided to use the bubble sort in this program? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: In my experience, bubble sort is self-explanatory, but people go about it a bit differently, its hard to tell how you do it without looking at every method, or what values you get back from the if/while statements. But my guess from what I do see is you just lost the reference to the very first one on accident. So its a logic error. And what I mean is instead of using temp, just use current. Leave temp alone so you always have a reference to the head. If you never touch it, it'll be there.

Comment: @DaveShaw : Seems like your whole idea of Bubble sort seems to have lost the way you doing the coding part. In Bubble Sort, we start with the first two elements and proceed till the end to find the max of them all and put the max at the end of the list, that is PASS 1, Now we repeat the steps till whole of the list is sorted out. I guess total number of passes = totalSizeOfTheList - 1. After that the whole list sorts out. Do check the algorithm again for bubble sort.  Regards

Comment: @MitchWheat +1 Only a madman would ever sort a linked list, or use bubble sort at all, let alone use bubble sort on a linked list. Or an undergraduate of course, at the direction of some mad professor ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your code is that header and tail get never updated.

Try the following simpler code:

```
public void sortStudentsAlphabeticallyByFirstName()
{
    StudentNode unsorted = tail;
    StudentNode current = header;
    while(unsorted.prevNode() != null)
    {
        while(current != unsorted)
        {
            StudentNode next = current.nextNode();
            int result = (current.getFirstName()).compareToIgnoreCase(next.getFirstName());
            if (result>0) // current is greater than next
            {
                // need to exchange : next will be before current
                //   HEADER (before) CURRENT NEXT (after) TAIL
                //   HEADER (before) NEXT CURRENT (after) TAIL

                // 1 - Before current
                if (current.prevNode() != null)
                    current.prevNode().setNext(next);
                else header = next;

                // 2 - After next
                if (next.nextNode() != null)
                    next.nextNode().setPrev(current);
                else tail = current;

                // 3 - current <-> next
                current.setNext(next.nextNode());
                next.setPrev(current.prevNode());
                current.setPrev(next);
                next.setNext(current);

                // Don't need to update current which is
                // already pointing to the greatest element
            }
            // next is greater than current -> update current
            else current = current.nextNode();
        }
        current = header;
        unsorted = unsorted.prevNode();
    }
}
```